# Titanium Android Map java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: android, google-maps, titanium, titanium-mobile, android-maps-v2

I have a MapView in my Android Titanium app. When I try to zoom in past a certain point the map appears blurry and I get this error in the console:

```
[ERROR] :  REQUEST: ERROR
[ERROR] :  REQUEST: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1
[ERROR] :  REQUEST:     at org.appcelerator.titanium.util.TiResponseCache.get(TiResponseCache.java:276)
[ERROR] :  REQUEST:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.OkResponseCacheAdapter.get(OkResponseCacheAdapter.java:38)
[ERROR] :  REQUEST:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.initResponseSource(HttpEngine.java:224)
[ERROR] :  REQUEST:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:185)
[ERROR] :  REQUEST:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:345)
[ERROR] :  REQUEST:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:89)
[ERROR] :  REQUEST:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:197)
[ERROR] :  REQUEST:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
[ERROR] :  REQUEST:     at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.b.l.run(Unknown Source)
[ERROR] :  REQUEST:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

The error shows up also when I try to switch the map from NORMAL_TYPE to HYBRID_TYPE and the map is blank (it only shows small squares and the Google logo).

I'm using Titanium SDK 3.4.0 on MacOSX and testing on Android 4.4.4.

Does anybody know how to solve it? Thank you

EDIT: 
Here is the code that calls and shows the map

map.xml

```
<Alloy>
    <Window id="mapWin" titleid="map" class="vertical" modal="false">
        <View id="mapContainer">
            <Module id="mView" module="ti.map" method="createView"></Module>
            <View id="buttonsOverlayTop">
                <View id="buttons">
                    <View id="buttonContainer1"></View>
                    <View id="buttonContainer2"></View>
                    <View id="buttonContainer3"></View>
                </View>
                <View id="buttonContainer4">
                    <Button id="changeMap">Satellite</Button>
                </View>
            </View>
        </View>
    </Window>
</Alloy>
```

map.js

```
var Map = require('ti.map');
var mView = $.mView;

$.changeMap.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        if (changeMap.title == 'Satellite') {
            changeMap.title = 'Standard';
            mView.mapType = Map.HYBRID_TYPE;
        } else {
            changeMap.title = 'Satellite';
            mView.mapType = Map.NORMAL_TYPE;
        }
    });
$.mapWin.addEventListener('open', function() {
        showTestPoint();
}

function showTestPoint(){
    mView.region = {
        latitude : 48.775640,
        longitude : 9.179520,
        latitudeDelta : 0.1,
        longitudeDelta : 0.1
    };
    var params = {
        latitude : 48.775640,
        longitude : 9.179520,
        title : "test",
        animate : true
    };

    var ann = Map.createAnnotation(params);

    mView.addAnnotation(ann);
}
```

Comment: what is code at line no 38 ?

Comment: I think that the error comes from the compiled Java, so I can't access the compiled file and see what's on line 38.

Comment: This is a bug in Titanium. Watch this issue: https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TC-4892